# How to specify the item for a sales order?

Tags: web-services, netsuite

My program finds orders in a database outside NetSuite and enters them in NetSuite through SuiteTalk.

I'm having trouble specifying the item for sales order lines.

My order line creation code looks like this:
[image]

When I try to specify the item using only the the RecordRef.name property I get an error saying "Please choose an item to add".

I am more successful when using RecordRef.internalId. I can look this up (not shown in the code above) using ItemSearchBasic and setting the ItemSearchBasic.externalId property as a list of RecordRefs each specifying an externalId value from the order lines in the source database. I seem to have to set the type property of each RecordRef. The problem is that I don't know the type. Some of the products are Inventory Item and some are Lot Numbered Assembly/Bill of Materials.

How can I specify the item for an order line without having to tell NetSuite what the type of the item is?

Comment: Have you tried using itemId? From the Schema browser in Netsuite docs seemed to show itemId

Comment: @TMann This is the answer. Write it as such and I'll tick you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use itemId - From the Schema browser in Netsuite docs show itemId as the proper internal id to use for item